# The 8 vectors to be made non-collinear

Tags: determinant, vector-analysis

Consider the set of $8$ vectors $V=\{ai+bj+ck:a,b,c \in \{-1,1\}\}$. How can I choose three non-collinear vectors from $V$?

**My try:**

Let there be three vectors
\begin{align*}
V_1&=a_1i+b_1j+c_1k,\\
V_2&=a_2i+b_2j+c_2k,\\
V_3&=a_3i+b_3j+c_3k.
\end{align*}

Now for $V_1,V_2,V_3$ to be collinear determinant of their $x,y,z$ components should be zero. But what next? What conditions should I apply?

Comment: A harder question would be to find three different of these vectors that _are_ collinear ...

Answer (score 1):

If you visualize the set of vectors, you will notice that they form the vertices of a cube. Since *no* three vertices of the cube are collinear, any choice of $V_1,V_2,V_3$ as three disctinct vectos of the set will do.

Let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ be any three distinct vectors of the set $V$.
Note that $V_2-V_1$ is a nonzero vector with components $\in\{-2,0,2\}$. Likewise, $V_3-V_1$ and $V_3-V_2$ are nonzero vectors with components $\in\{-2,0,2\}$. 
The only way for $V_3-V_1$ to be a multiple of $V_2-V_1$ which is equivalent to collinearity of $V_1,V_2,V_3$) is therefore that $V_3-V_1=\pm(V_2-V_1)$. But "$+$" leads to $V_3=V_2$, contrary to assumption. So $V_3-V_1=-(V_2-V_1)$ and hence $V_3-V_2=2\cdot (V_1-V_2)$ is a nonzero vector with components in $\{-4,0,4\}$. But we already know that its components are $\in\{-2,0,2\}$, so they must be zero, i.e. again $V_3=V_2$ contrary to assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product of any two of the three vectors you choose cannot be zero.  With the constraints you have, this in essence means that none of the vectors you choose can be the same as, or the negative of, any of the others.

So $(1,1,1), (1,1,-1), (1,-1,1)$ would work, for example.

Comment: You mean eleven such pairs?

Comment: You're only asked to find three non-colinear vectors.  Where does the $11$ come from?

Comment: How many such pairs will be there?not a particular solution.

Comment: I don't know.  I'd have to count them.  But that seems to be a different question.

Comment: I don't think your argument that the vectors cannot be the negative of each other works. For example, $(1,1,1)$, $(-1,-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1,1)$ are not collinear. I think you may be confusing "collinear" with "linearly dependent"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm if a vector is the negative of another vector, it's antiparallel.  $(1,1,1)$ points in exactly the opposite direction of $(-1, -1, -1)$.

Comment: @John: That means the line between those two points goes through the origin, but so what? The third point is _not_ on that line, so they are not collinear.

Comment: If that's the case, then what does this question mean?  All of the eight vectors go through the origin.  The only thing that differentiates them is their direction.  By your reasoning, none of the eight vectors can be collinear.  I don't think that's the point of the question.